# Redirected you too many times on firebase hosted reactjs PWA

Tags: reactjs, dns, cloudflare, firebase-hosting, custom-domain

I just bought a domain on cloudflare and I'm trying to put my project to it. My project is a reactjs based PWA. I'm trying to follow the instructions but running in an error. It was showing too many ADMEA redirects earlier. It's not showing that now on firestore but it still shows up when i try to go to my new domain on web.
It is also asking me to add another DNS record even though I have already added that through my cloudfare DNS settings as seen in the images. I have waited 24+ hours.

[image]

[image]

It also keeps asking me on firestore to remove some DNS records even though I don't have them on DNS records on my cloudflare account.
Please advise.

[image]